# How to Hide a Title Bar in a CDockablePane?

Tags: mfc, mdi, titlebar, dockpanel

I want to hide a title bar in `CDockablePane`. I tried calling `ModifyStyle()`, but it doesn't work.

```
ModifyStyle(WS_SYSMENU, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

Comment: Where do you see the title? In the docked or undocked state?

Comment: In the docked state. Several dockable panes are docked with tabs. there is a title on the tab, and also on the title bar of docked window. So I just want to remove one(title bar).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the style WS_CAPTION when you create the pane!

Answer (score 0):

you need to call dockablepane's EnableGripper(FALSE) to hide the pane's caption in docking state. Remember to call it when creating tabbedpane as well.

Answer (score 0):

The function `CDockablePane::Create()` has a parameter called `BOOL bHasGripper` which is usually set to `TRUE` while in your case you can set it to `FALSE`, like below.

```
class COutputWnd : public CDockablePane {};
COutputWnd m_wndOutput;
if (!m_wndOutput.Create(strOutputWnd, this, CRect(0, 0, 100, 100), FALSE, ID_VIEW_OUTPUTWND, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | CBRS_BOTTOM | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI))
{
    return FALSE; // failed to create
}
```